# React relay with NextJS: RelayContext: Expected `context.relay` to be an object conforming to the `RelayContext` interface, got `[object Object]`

Tags: reactjs, next.js, relayjs, react-relay

I have setup my Relay environment like this:

```
// createRelayEnvironment.ts

let relayEnvironment

export default function initEnvironment({ records }: EnvProps) {
    // Create a network layer from the fetch function
    const network = Network.create(fetchQuery)

    const store = new Store(new RecordSource(records || {}))

    // Make sure to create a new Relay environment for every server-side request so that data
    // isn't shared between connections
    if (!(process as any).browser) {
        return new Environment({
            network,
            store
        })
    }

    // reuse Relay environment on client-side
    if (!relayEnvironment) {
        relayEnvironment = new Environment({
            network,
            store
        })
    }

    return relayEnvironment
}
```

and to fetch data:

```
class WithData extends React.Component {
        environment: Environment

        constructor(props: any) {
            super(props)
            this.environment = initEnvironment({
                records: props.queryRecords
            })
        }


        static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
            let composedInitialProps = {}
            if (ComposedComponent.getInitialProps) {
                composedInitialProps = await ComposedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx)
            }

            let queryProps = {}
            let queryRecords = {}

            const environment = initEnvironment({ records: {} })

            if (options.query) {
                const variables = options.mapProps ? options.mapProps() : {}
here
                queryProps = await fetchQuery(environment, options.query, variables)

                queryRecords = environment.getStore().getSource().toJSON()
            }

            return {
                ...ctx.query, // query info from next-router. E.g "slug"
                ...composedInitialProps,
                ...queryProps,
                queryRecords
            }
        }

        render() {
            const relay = {
                environment: this.environment
            }

            return (
                <ReactRelayContext.Provider value={{ environment: this.environment }}>
                    <ComposedComponent {...(this.props as P)} {...{ relay }} />
                </ReactRelayContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: RelayContext: Expected `context.relay` to be an object conforming to the `RelayContext` interface, got `[object Object]`.
```

This is happening with NextJS 11 and Relay v6.0.0. It was working fine on v5.0.0. These are quite old versions but I'm trying to upgrade.

From looking at [the source code](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/7ee39e40258e11bc24156e74b5fdeaa01eb73a64/packages/react-relay/isRelayEnvironment.js#L19), this suggests the Relay environment is not the right format, but I don't see how this can be the case since I'm just following the doc's [initialisation instructions](https://relay.dev/docs/v6.0.0/quick-start-guide#relay-environment)

Is there something simple I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked out what was causing this. The check that was failing was [this line](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/b7501c6472b34ae2b0bb8cc164a648bb90749d74/packages/react-relay/RelayContext.js#L43) in the Relay source code.

When I added an empty object for variables, like this:

```
render() {
            const relay = {
                environment: this.environment
            }

            return (
                <ReactRelayContext.Provider value={{ environment: this.environment, variables: {}}>
                    <ComposedComponent {...(this.props as P)} {...{ relay }} />
                </ReactRelayContext.Provider>
            )
        }
```

it worked.

The downside is this now fails typescript checks. But I notice that in v7, the validation in the source code has now gone. So for me the solution has been to upgrade to v7 and remove the variables.